# A seemingly silly quesition about integrating expression containing partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Consider

$$f = x R$$

Take the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ at constant $y$. By the product rule,

$$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} )_y = R + x (\frac{\partial R}{\partial x})_y$$

Then integrate with respect to $x$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$.

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} )_y dx= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} [R + x (\frac{\partial R}{\partial x})_y]dx$$

$$\Delta f=  R\Delta x + \int_{x_1}^{x_2}x (\frac{\partial R}{\partial x})_y dx$$

Okay, so now for the actual question. I assume that you cannot take the $x$ out of the integral in the last equation, but the derivation I'm looking at suggests otherwise. Am I crazy? Or is there some how a difference between that $x$ and the the $x$ I'm integrating with respect to?

Comment: Is $R$ a function of $x$? If so, then how is it that in last equation you obtained $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}Rdx = R\Delta x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is precisely what integration by parts means, taking into account that your last equation seems to be wrong. Note that you are differentiating on $x$ and integrating on $x$ too, so $y$ plays no role and we can ignore it completely for this discussion.
Assume
$$
f(x) = x R(x)
$$
Of course, if we differentiate $f(x)$ we obtain $\frac{df}{dx} = R(x) + x\frac{dR}{dx}$, and if we integrate this equation from $x_1$ to $x_2$ in both sides we obtain:
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{df}{dx}dx = f(x_2) - f(x_1) =\int_{x_1}^{x_2}R(x)dx + \int_{x_1}^{x_2} x \frac{dR}{dx}dx
$$
and not what you obtained unless $R(x) = r$ is constant. In this case,
$$
f(x_2) - f(x_1) = r(x_2-x_1)
$$
which is what you have expected. You can also see how this is correct, if you integrate by parts $x \frac{dR}{dx}$ directly:
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} x \frac{dR}{dx}dx = xR(x)|_{x_1}^{x_2} - \int_{x_1}^{x_2} R(x)dx = f(x_2)-f(x_1) - \int_{x_1}^{x_2} R(x)dx 
$$
So, answering to your questions directly: You can't take the $x$ out of the integral. And yes, the $x$ in the integral and the $x$ in the $dx$ are the same.

I hope this helps!

P.S., for $f(x,y)$, the only difference is that we take $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ instead of $\frac{d}{dx}$ but all my points remain the same.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, R(x) = r. My bad about that. 

This absolutely answers my question. This question is coming from a thermodynamics scenario, and I must have let the renaming of things get to my head. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Good luck! (don't forget to mark this question as correct then)